# blender backface culling switch frontface 3D

Tags: 3d, blender

I want to connect two tubes with faces, "Make / Edge, Face" (F). I've activated Backface Culling to see the front but not the back of the faces. 
After a few faces I recognized that the front and back of the face I made has changed (red Points in the image). I want to make faces like the green one, how can I switch between front and back in blender?
The link to the image is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0uUr.png

Comment: You may want to check out the blender site of stack exchange ;) http://blender.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flip the normals on that face, so with the face selected go to: **Mesh > Faces > Flip Normals**

The order in which you select vertices (CW or CCW) would have an effect on the face normal's direction I assume.